# Django - Create model with fields derivable from other model

Tags: python, django

I have 2 Django models representing the coin domain.
The Coin has some properties and the trading Pair is based on those properties.

```
class Coin(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32) 

class Pair(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    base_currency = models.ForeignKey(Coin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='base_currency')
    quote_currency = models.ForeignKey(Coin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='quote_currency')
```

Let's add a couple of Coin instances:

```
first = Coin.objects.create(code="BTC", name="Bitcoin")
second = Coin.objects.create(code="USD", name="United States Dollar")
```

and one Pair:

```
Pair.objects.create(code="BTCUSD", name="Bitcoin / United States Dollar", base_currency=first, quote_currency=second)
```

As you can see, **code** and **name** in the *Pair* model can be derived from code and name in the Coin model.
To put it simple:

- Pair Code = First Coin Code + Second Coin Code
- Pair Name = First Coin Name + "/" + Second Coin Name

But, in this example I simply hardcoded those values and for sure this is not the best way to handle this situation.
For example: what if in the Coin model I need to change the name of an instance?
Then, I will have to manually update *code* and *name* in the Pair model, because this values are not properly binded from the Coin Model.

I believe Pair code/name must be binded/derived from the Coin model in some way.

Is there a way to do that in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not need to store the name of your `Pair` since it can be infered from the references from `Pair.base_currency` and `Pair.quote_currency`.

A property on the `Pair` class should be enough:

```py
class Pair(models.Model):
    base_currency = models.ForeignKey(Coin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='base_currency')
    quote_currency = models.ForeignKey(Coin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='quote_currency')

    @property
    def code(self) -> str:
        return self.base_currency.code + self.quote_currency.code

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.base_currency.name} / {self.quote_currency.name}'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine.
Is it possible to use a Django Rest Framework serializer for Pair, in order to allow the user to put via JSON something like {"pair" : "BTCUSD"} and see if the value is matching the code property?